# Unable to get percent_indicator dependency in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use percent_indicator in my flutter project. When I give `flutter pub get` the following error I'm getting. This occurs only for this dependency. I tried the solution mentioned in the following link

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46641#issuecomment-631359661

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65785014/9455775

Error I'm getting
Handshake error in client (OS Error:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake.cc:354))

pub upgrade failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...

Handshake error in client (OS Error:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake.cc:354))

pub upgrade failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...

.
.
.
.
(Goes on )
But still no use.. Please let me know what went wrong here .

Answer (score 0):

1- try to disable your antivirus | firewall

2- try to use vpn

3- run your cmd promt with anadministrator privileges and try again

restart your IDE before trying again

Comment: vpn is connected . but still not able to get it

Comment: what about antivirus and did you restart the IDE ?

Comment: Yes I restarted

Comment: try to run your cmd promt with anadministrator privileges and try again

Comment: No luck . still the same. For all other dependency pub get is  working fine. Only for this dependency its like this

Comment: that's weird .. I tried downloading it just now and it worked fine !

Comment: this issue happens with other indicator dependencies too which is really weird

Answer (score 0):

Created new project and added the dependency. It worked for me